# Can't get dep and dockerize working together in docker-compose (but they work separately). Why?

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I have a curious situation where my docker-compose build won't complete when I use `dockerize` to wait for databases etc to be ready, and use `dep` to load my Go dependencies.

Here's an extract from docker-compose.yml (there are mosquitto, postgres, and python containers in addition to the golang container shown below)

```
version '3.3'
services:

   foobar_container:
     image: foobar_image
     container_name: foobar
     build:
      context: ./build_foobar
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.foobar
     #command: dockerize -wait tcp://mosquitto:1883 -wait tcp://postgres:5432 -timeout 200s /go/src/foobar/main
     volumes:
       - ./foobar:/go
     stdin_open: true
     tty: true
     external_links:
       - mosquitto
       - postgres
     ports:
       - 1833
       - 8001
     depends_on:
       - mosquitto
       - postgres
```

Here's my Dockerfile.foobar

```
FROM golang:latest
 WORKDIR /go
 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget mosquitto-clients net-tools
 ENV DOCKERIZE_VERSION v0.6.0
 RUN wget https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize/releases/download/$DOCKERIZE_VERSION/dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz \
   && tar -C /usr/local/bin -xzvf dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz \
   && rm dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz
 ADD foobar.sh /foobar.sh
 #RUN go build main.go
 RUN chmod +x /foobar.sh
```

Here's my build script foobar.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /go/bin # required directory that may have been overwriten by docker-compose `volumes` param
echo "++++++++ Downloading Golang dependencies ... ++++++++"
cd /go/src/foobar
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh | sh
echo "++++++++ Installing Golang dependencies ... ++++++++"
dep ensure
echo "++++++++ Testing MQTT message broker ... ++++++++"
until [[ $(mosquitto_sub -h "mosquitto" -t '$SYS/#' -C 1 | cut -c 1-9) = "mosquitto" ]]; do
    echo "++++++++ Message broker is not ready. Waiting one second... ++++++++"
    sleep 1
done
echo "++++++++ Building application... ++++++++" 
go build main.go
```

If I uncomment the `command` line of `docker-compose.yml` my `foobar.sh` won't run past the `curl` line. No error is outputted, the execution just stops.
If I comment from `curl` onwards, and uncomment the `command` line, I can setup to completion (however the `foobar` container needs to me started manually). My python container (which depends on all postgres, go, and mosquitto containers) sets up fine.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Could you provide the logs for the foobar_container? `docker-compose logs foobar_container`

Comment: `foobar.sh` isn't executed inside the container, as far as the files you provided. Is there something missing?

Comment: Yes, I didn't show the "master" setup script that pulls the latest code from the repository, runs `docker-compose up`, and then executes the build scripts for each container (including `foohar.sh`). Gimme a minute on the logs; I've found a postgres connection issue in foobar's log.

Comment: Is that the order of execution? because it should execute `foobar.sh` before executing the `dockerize` command. If you run `docker-compose up`, dockerize command executes. Could you share it? at least the pertinent parts.

Comment: Ugh you're right. I can't run `main` until `main.go` is built, so I can't run `main` from `dockerize`. It's only working because I happen to have built a local binary which is getting copied into the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things I found, first the execution order, you must ensure the `foobar.sh` gets executed first. As another recommendation, I wouldn't override the entire `/go` folder inside the container using volumes, instead use another subfolder, e.g `/go/github.com/my-project`.
I got an app running using this configuration, based on yours:

`build_foobar/Dockerfile.foobar`:

```
FROM golang:latest
WORKDIR /go
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget mosquitto-clients net-tools
ENV DOCKERIZE_VERSION v0.6.0
RUN wget https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize/releases/download/$DOCKERIZE_VERSION/dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz \
        && tar -C /usr/local/bin -xzvf dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz \
        && rm dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz
ADD foobar.sh /foobar.sh
# RUN go build main.go
RUN chmod +x /foobar.sh
```

`build_foobar/foobar.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# mkdir -p /go/bin # required directory that may have been overwriten by docker-compose `volumes` param
echo "++++++++ Downloading Golang dependencies ... ++++++++"
cd /go/src/foobar
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh | sh
echo "++++++++ Installing Golang dependencies ... ++++++++"
dep ensure
echo "++++++++ Testing MQTT message broker ... ++++++++"
until [[ $(mosquitto_sub -h "mosquitto" -t '$SYS/#' -C 1 | cut -c 1-9) = "mosquitto" ]]; do
    echo "++++++++ Message broker is not ready. Waiting one second... ++++++++"
    sleep 1
done
echo "++++++++ Building application... ++++++++" 
go build main.go

dockerize -wait tcp://mosquitto:1883 -wait tcp://postgres:5432 -timeout 200s /go/src/foobar/main
```

`foobar/main.go`: place your app main file

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  foobar_container:
    image: foobar_image
    container_name: foobar
    build:
      context: ./build_foobar
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.foobar
    # command: dockerize -wait tcp://mosquitto:1883 -wait tcp://postgres:5432 -timeout 200s /go/src/foobar/main
    # command: /bin/bash
    command: /foobar.sh
    volumes:
      - ./foobar:/go/src/foobar
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    external_links:
      - mosquitto
      - postgres
    depends_on:
      - mosquitto
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 1833
      - 8001
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
  postgres:
    image: postgres
```

Comment: Thanks! With your astute comments about logs and order of execution I was able to resolve several obscure bugs (certain db tables missing that were created by other applications, etc) and get it working.

Comment: nice to hear it! Keep it up!